# Condition Comparison

Tags: c

I am writing the exit part of my simple C shell.

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    while(1){
        char input_line[MAX], *tokens[X_MAX];
        int i,n; //n is the number of tokens inside the *tokens
        .
        .
        .//gets the input from user and stores into tokens
        .
        if(n ==1){
            char *ex = "exit";
            printf("difference: %i\n",strcmp(tokens[0],ex));  //this prints out 10
        }


    }
}
```

I am stuck on the part when they differ when obviously they aren't. What I am trying to do is that when the user types in "exit" (which is stored in a char array "tokens"), the if statement picks it up and then it compares it to the one stored in "ex".

Any idea?

thanks

Comment: Check for extra whitespace in the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's most likely you're not trimming the string you get from the user and it still contains the newline, `'\n'`. I jumped to this condition because `\n` is 10 in ASCII.

---

For trimming I use this:

```
for (p = line + strlen(line) - 1; p >= line && isspace(*p); --p)
        ;

p[1] = 0;
```

Not sure where I got it or if it's mine. Probably not mine though.

Comment: how would you trim it? do I just store it back to the original variable less the last spot in the array?

Comment: @user1234440 There are many examples of string-trimming function on stackoverflow. Your way is probably OK but you should also look at what others tried.

Comment: lol, bad practice but, just add "\n" to the "ex" variables at the end solves it. Thanks so much!

Comment: @user1234440 :-)) Until you end up on thedailywtf. Glad I could help though :-)